# Can't get an Ethernet connection between a PRO/1000 GT Desktop Adapter and a Beckhoff module working

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-adapter, opensuse

I'm using openSUSE 11 (i586) installed on a PC used for an old project.

I have a problem with the network card (Intel PRO/1000 GT Desktop Adapter). Connecting the Ethernet cable to a Beckhoff module (EK1100), the light on the PC port lights up, while nothing happens on the module. This is the case even if connected to a switch instead of the Beckhoff module.

The Beckhoff module has been tested with another PC and it works fine.

I have already done several things, non of which worked:

- Changed the cable
- Changed network card slot in the PCI
- Reinstalled the network card driver (e1000)

Does anybody with more experience know what the problem could be?